# Clever way to simplify sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, summation

Is there a clever way to rewrite the sum

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n} (x_i-x_{i-1})\left(\frac{(x_i-x_{i-1})}{2}-x_i \right)
?$$

I haven't been able to come up with anything useful thus far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that
$$(a-b)\left(\frac{a-b}{2}-a\right)=(a-b)\cdot\left(\frac{-a-b}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)$$
so that
$$\sum_{i=2}^{n} (x_i-x_{i-1})\left(\frac{(x_i-x_{i-1})}{2}-x_i \right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=2}^n(x_{i-1}^2-x_i^2)=\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2-x_n^2)$$